# Why did Urquhart choose "neck of a goose" in his English translation of Gargantua?

Tags: french-language, translation, francois-rabelais, gargantua-and-pantagruel

In Rabelais' Gargantua, in Chapter 13, we find a discussion on the best means to wipe one's bum.

You can find Urquhart's translation [here](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Gargantua/Chapter_XIII). I am specifically interested in the conclusion:

> But, to conclude, I say and maintain, that of all torcheculs,
> arsewisps, bumfodders, tail-napkins, bunghole cleansers, and
> wipe-breeches, there is none in the world comparable *to the neck of a
> goose, that is well downed*, if you hold her head betwixt your legs

(emphasis mine)

In Rabelais' original, this is:

> Mais, concluent, je dys et mantiens qu’il n’y a tel torchecul que d’*un
> oyzon bien dumeté*, pourveu qu’on luy tienne la teste entre les jambes

(emphasis mine -- [source](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Rabelais_marty-laveaux_01.djvu/75))

Which in contemporary French is typically rendered as "oisillon bien duveté" i.e.,:

- "oisillon" — a baby bird, a fledgling
- "bien duveté" — fluffy, well downed

---

Why did Urquhart pick "goose", and even more specifically, "neck of a goose"?

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice first question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a *oisillon*, it's a *oison*.

A *oison* is a *gosling*, i.e., a baby goose. See [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oison). (A *oie* is a goose; knowing this is what made me look *oison* up in the dictionary.)

So why did Urquhart pick *goose* and not *gosling*? I don't know. It seems like a translation error to me. He did at least get the right species, but I expect a gosling's down feathers are even softer than a goose's.

Why the *neck*? Presumably because, if you're holding a goose's head between your legs, the neck is the part that is in the appropriate position.

Why do some contemporary French sources translate it from Rabelais' French as a *oisillon bien duveté*? Maybe that's also a translation error.

Comment: Thank you very much. _oison_ rather than _oisillon_ makes sense, and the probable explanation regarding _neck_ does as well. I really appreciate it!

Comment: For what it's worth, the Russian translation has it as "что нет лучшей подтирки, чем _гусенок с нежным пушком_" ([source](https://www.litmir.me/br/?b=22736&p=6)) i.e. a gosling (гусенок) with soft (нежным) down/fluff (пушком).

Comment: @Peter *Why do some contemporary French sources translate it from Rabelais' French as a oisillon bien duveté?* Because the word *oison* is essentially unknown to contemporary native French readers and *oisillon*, despite losing the "goose" part, is better than potential alternatives like *bébé oie* or worst: *oisillon d'oie*.

Comment: @jlliagre: Losing the "goose" part is unfortunate, because goose down is famously soft. But such are the difficulties of translation, even from Old French to modern French. I guess an alternative would be to use *oison* with a footnote.

Comment: @Peter I guess *oisillon* (which suggests *poussin*)'s down is soft enough for the intended purpose ;-)